# I am unable to navigate to target page on Riasedbutton click

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to Navigate to two different screens on two different button clicks, I am using Navigator.push() method to redirect myself on button click but doesn't work.

I have changed my Main.dart to a stateful widget instead of the by default stateless

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:relationship/screens/form_screen.dart';
import 'package:relationship/screens/personal_log.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyApp createState() => _MyApp();
}

class _MyApp extends State<MyApp> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              // ignore: deprecated_member_use
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PersonalOg()));
                },
                child: Text("Personal Log"),
              ),
              // ignore: deprecated_member_use
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FormClass()));
                },
                child: Text("Lover Log"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigator is built after `MaterialApp` and it doesn't exist in the current `context`. Try wrapping the `Scaffold` with a `Builder` widget to get a new `context` after `MaterialApp`.

```dart
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    await Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Personalog()));
                  },
                  child: Text("Personal Log"),
                ),
                // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FormClass()));
                  },
                  child: Text("Lover Log"),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: How will I do that?>